# Linking two user accounts together

Tags: php, user-accounts

I am building a method for users of my website to link their accounts together, so that resources can be shared between them. My process so far is:

- 1) User enters email addresses of users he wants to link with.
- 2) If matches are found, these users receive an email.
- 3) Email contains a confirmation link. If the recipient clicks this, the connection between the two accounts will be formed.

I'm wondering how secure I need to be with this final step. My confirmation link is in the format: `domain.com/link-confirm.php?fromid=xxx&toid=yyy`

In theory, it would be possible for anyone to spoof this link, if they knew the user id of their target, thus setting up a connection without permission.

I tried hashing both user ids, then scanning through the user database for matches, but the `password_verify` function takes so long to run that the page times out (and that's with only 1000 users).

What I would like to know is:
Does my plan above make sense?
Is there a neater way of doing it?
Am I right to be concerned about the spoofing (connecting the accounts does not in itself share any data between users, it merely makes it possible for either user to initiate)?

Thanks

Comment: you can just encrypt both id values and after obtaining it from get - decrypt them, hashes don't need to be used here. That way it will take thousands of years for somebody to brute force spoof them.

Comment: Encrypt, hash or generate information in the URL. `url?id=somegeneratedstring` and you should have a table that converts the hashed or generated string to a username and secondary username id's. By adding an additional timestamp column that updates on `INSERT` you can also set an link expiry time.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. @n-dru: I went with your encryption idea and it works quite neatly. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rob Thanks man, glad to hear that! OK, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just encrypt both id values and after obtaining it from get - decrypt them, hashes don't need to be used here. That way it will take thousands of years for somebody to brute force spoof them.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is generate some unique data per account linking request and require that unique data to be sent with the linking acceptance request.

So for example user A requests to link with user B, you store the request with some unique data like a random hash and a timestamp, and then when user B clicks "accept" in his email, he is sent to a page on your server. The link in the email contained the unique data that is submitted to the page. You check if the unique data is indeed the data that was generated when user A submitted the request, and, if so, boom, users linked.